# How to override `root_path` in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have locales defined like this:

```
# routes.rb
scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  ...
  root "home#index"
end
```

I also set locale in `default_url_params` in `ApplicationController`.
This way I have all my routes and urls to include locales like this:   http://example.com/en/something
http://example.com/fr/something
It is an expected behavior for me.

I also have root urls like this:
http://example.com/en
http://example.com/fr

What I want to achieve is **exclude** `en` (default) locale for `root_path`, so that `root_path` for `:en` locale (either passed explicitly or via `default_url_params`) is http://example.com/

Is there any way to do it?
Can I maybe override `root_path` to do my hacking inside it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

override `root_path` method in your `ApplicationController`:

```
def root_path
  (I18n.locale == 'en') ? '/' : super
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that this way I am risking some parts of code to call existent `root_path` (the ones that include route helpers but not ApplicationController)

Comment: Override them with `helper_method :root_path`. After that you'll get same method for controller & view

Comment: yep that's about what I ended up with. Thank you!